# Qt standard key stopped working in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I'm writing a program using

- Linux Mint 19
- Python version: 3.6.6
- Qt version: 5.9.5
- PyQt version: 5.10.1
- SIP version: 4.19.7

and I have just noticed that the standard short key for closing (`CTRL+W`) has stopped working.

In my file I've written the following line to connect it to the close button

```
self.closeBtn.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence.Close))
```

But nothing happens if I push the buttons. If I change it to

```
self.closeBtn.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.CTRL + QtCore.Qt.Key_W))
```

it works as intended.
I've also tried with

```
self.closeBtn.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence.Quit))
```

But `CTRL+Q` does nothing either. The standard keys work for other applications.
Any ideas on why that could be?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class demo_widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lay_content = QVBoxLayout()
        self.closeBtn = QPushButton("Close")
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()

        self.closeBtn.clicked.connect(self.slt_close)
        self.closeAction = QAction(self, triggered=self.slt_close)
        self.closeAction.setShortcuts([QKeySequence("Ctrl+Q"), QKeySequence("Ctrl+W")])
        self.closeBtn.addAction(self.closeAction)

        lay_content.addWidget(self.closeBtn)
        lay_content.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.setLayout(lay_content)

    def slt_close(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText("close")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication([])
    demo = demo_widget()
    demo.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: This didn't work either, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Tried this, but the result is the same, the app doesn't seem to register `CTRL+W` as `QtGui.QKeySequence.Close`

Answer (score 0):

> enum QKeySequence::StandardKey
>
> This enum represent standard key bindings.
> They can be used to assign platform dependent keyboard shortcuts to a QAction.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#StandardKey-enum

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyButton(QMainWindow):              
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        btn1 = QPushButton("Click or `Ctrl+Q`", clicked=self.close)
        btn1.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Q"))
        
        btn2    = QPushButton("QKeySequence.Close", 
                              clicked=lambda: print("\n Please Press -> Ctrl+W"))
        quitAct = QAction("Close", btn2, triggered=self.close)
        quitAct.setShortcuts(QKeySequence.Close)                     # <<<=======
        btn2.addAction(quitAct)
        
        btn3 = QPushButton("Click or `Ctrl+P`", clicked=lambda: print("Hello Kajsa"))
        btn3.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+P"))
        
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)        
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        v_layout.addWidget(btn1)
        v_layout.addWidget(btn2)
        v_layout.addWidget(btn3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication([])
    mb = MyButton()
    mb.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to say?

Comment: @Kajsa `QKeySequence :: StandardKey` This enum represent standard key bindings. They can be used to assign platform dependent keyboard shortcuts to a `QAction`. !!! `to a QAction` !!!

Comment: I know, but why does it not work anymore? The same standard key can close other applications, like Firefox or File manager, but nothing happens when I use it in the pyhton3 script. It used to work but doesn't anymore.